# How to position List view

Tags: listview, swiftui, positioning

I have following code in my struct View

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Section("Measurements") {
                ForEach(meaHeaders, id: \.id) { measurement in
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Text(measurement.name!)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        HStack {
                            Text(measurement.desc ?? "").font(.caption)
                            Spacer()
                        }
                    }
                }.swipeActions() {
                    Button("Delete") {
                        
                    }.tint(.red)
                    Button("Edit") {
                        newMeasurement.toggle()
                    }.tint(.blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }.toolbar() {
        Button(action: {
            newMeasurement = true
        }, label: {
            Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
        }).sheet(isPresented: $newMeasurement) {
            NewMeasurement(showMe: $newMeasurement, processID: processID)
        }
    }
}
```

which is presented as shown on attached screenshot[image: screenshot]
I'm wondering how to push List view to the top. I tried various Spacers but none worked properly.

Comment: In the future, try asking using a minimal reproducible code example... This question would be more concise if you removed the `.swipeActions()` and `.toolbar()` and various stacks

Comment: Looks like a double NavigationView - you only need one at the topmost level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downwards offset is due to the `NavigationView`. `NavigationView`s are horribly annoying in SwiftUI, particularly due to this effect they have. You can either remove the `NavigationView` entirely or remove the `NavigationBar` with `.navigationBarHidden()` to bump your view back up. Alternatively, you could offset the view with `.offset()`, but this may compromise some functionality.

Unless you want the `NavigationView`, I would recommend getting rid of it and implementing your own navigation.

**Note**: `.navigationBarHidden()` is a little buggy, and you may need to set the navigation title to "" for it to work.